# How can one figure out if equations in presentation of a group are independent or not?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-presentation

*Note: My question is not directly about solving the below problem.*

> Let $G$ be a group with presentation given by $$G= \langle a,b,c \mid ab =c^2a^4,bc=ca^6,ac=ca^8,c^{2018}=b^{2019}\rangle.$$ Determine order of the group $G$.

In the above problem, we see that the group is defined by four equations.

My question is, how do we know if these equations are independent?

For instance, how could we know if $ab=c^2 a^4$ and $bc=ca^6$ implies $ac=ca^8$ or not? Is there some easy algorithim for this?

I think this is in some way related to inverted linear equation to write unknowns in term of coefficients, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: "how do we know if this equations are independent? For instance, how could we know if $ab=c^2 a^4$ and $bc=ca^6$ implies $ac=ca^8$ or not? " Just by a counterexample with some group where the first two relations hold, but not the last one. It it follows, it usually can be shown easily in such an example. But in general - again- we cannot say much from a presentation, see the links at your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4619614/is-there-a-general-theorem-to-figure-out-order-of-a-group-from-its-polynomial-r).

Comment: This is in general (in the nonabelian case) an extremely hard problem that cannot have a general solution in the Turing Machine model. See *Word Problem* or *Dehn's Problems*. In the abelian case it is solved by the *Smith Normal Form*.

Comment: @ahulpke That would make a good answer.

Comment: damn I wonder for what reason someone tried to close this...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is in general (in the nonabelian case) an extremely hard problem that cannot have a general solution in the Turing Machine model. See [*Word Problem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_problem_(mathematics)) or *Dehn's Problems*.
This does not preclude some approaches working in particular cases.

In the abelian case it is solved by the *Smith Normal Form*.

Comment: Perhaps also mention [Dehn's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_cancellation_theory#Dehn.27s_algorithm)?